# Rename or delete 'My account' top link in header Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, login, magento-community, toplinks

By now, I have 'My account' (with its dropdown menu) next to 'Log in' in my home page.

I want to only have a 'Log in' button that changes to 'Log out' when user is logged.

I've been trying with local.xml but couldn't succeed. I know I should edit something there but can't find out what.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `customer.xml` to your theme (if it's not there already). Then remove OR comment below line:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

For changing `Name/Title`, you can update the values of above `xml's` `<label>` and `<title>` tags, like:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>CUSTOM NAME</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>CUSTOM NAME</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

Comment: You say the customer.xml from app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout? Because I'm uploading from FTP and see no change. It's really frustrating.

Comment: ys, copy `customer.xml` of your CURRENT THEME. Paste it here if possible

Comment: I could find the line:
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

But nothing happens if I remove or comment the line and reupload it.

Comment: Why is commenting not working?

Comment: After commenting or removing, clear cache

Answer (score 0):

You can get an idea that how you can edit top links in Magento 1, from below link:

http://www.webinse.com/blog/magento/top-links-in-magento-2/

However, below is code the code the to show login and logout link, depends on session:

```
 <?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo 'Logout'; ?></a>

        <?php 
    /*
    else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login</a>
        <?php 
    */
    endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but maybe is more information that what I need. I'm trying to leave just one button 'Log In" that changes to 'Log out' when session is started. Is it too hard? I'm very new to Magento. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mangus As I said, it is mentioned in the article. Kindly check it out. It is easy. And code which I shared, is the one you will be using.

Comment: Where should I include the code for session?